# Need one sample html javascript to do CRUD operation using Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Please could someone suggest one simple sample to do a CRUD operation using JavaScript and html.

something other than Authorizing users to login. Any details on how to create a collection as real time Firebase database also might help. I am unable to distinguish between the realtime and cloud firebase database and what settings to change on firebase console.

I am using windows 10

Attached is one sample I tried. I get this error when I run inspect on chrome developer tool. Not sure how to fix this.
firebase.js:284 WebSocket connection to 'wss://s-usc1c-nss-237.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ls=UvtePRbbSq4dLIKosL5wjLMlrd8zhhgf&ns=friendlyeats-31b8f' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

```js
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "firebase-keys",
  databaseURL: "firebase-keys",
  projectId: "friendlyeats-31b8f",
  storageBucket: "firebase-keys",
  messagingSenderId: "firebase-keys",
  appId: "firebase-keys",
  measurementId: "firebase-keys",
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

this.database = firebase.database();

console.log(this.database);

firebase
  .auth()
  .signInAnonymously()
.catch(function (error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    console.log("error");
  });

var ref = firebase.database().ref();

ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
  output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(snapshot.val(), null, 2);
});


--database.json.rules
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

--.firebaserc
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "friendlyeats-31b8f"
  }
}

--firebase.json
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <title>Firebase example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Firebase example</h1>
    <pre id="data"></pre>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google will land you on this article [Learn Firebase CRUD App with Vanilla JavaScript NOW](https://medium.com/@rajatamil/in-this-firebase-crud-javascript-web-tutorial-you-will-be-learning-how-to-do-create-update-and-c3ca4f4da15d)

P.S. Probably not a good idea to publish your Firebase keys publicly. Just replacing them with `{firebase-keys}` will do.